Can't find where OECD's Inflation (CPI) data got migrated
I used to look at EU CPI on OECD's Data site, switching to the table view, selecting EU27_2020 for the country and 2015=100 to have a fixed base instead of the yearly growth:

This data, however, stopped getting updates as of last November. There is a ⚠️ icon shown above the table with the tool tip "Indicator updates temporarily paused during website upgrade. Access latest OECD data here".
I followed the link to the new site, but I could not find the same data there. I found multiple CPI data sets, but I could not find a way to use a 2015=100 (or any other year) as a fixed base for any of them. Is this data accessible in this form on the new site somewhere?

I couldn't find this data on OECD's Data Explorer but I found it on Eurostat's Data Browser.
